# How to send Request-method for a simple client server http communication - through query string parameters or specifying separately?

Tags: c, linux, http, http-headers

I am working on a simple client server applications which utilize basic GET POST functionality. I had a question regarding specifying the GET or POST or any Request Method when we send a request from client to server. There is a separate "Request Method" as HTTP spec says should specify the method. But I do see some examples where we send the request method through Query Parameters. Which is proper way and what happens in case we also send a request method through query parameter? Which one should be considered by the server if by chance the one specified in query parameter differ from actual request method?

Comment: In which language? Which platform? Which version? Which universe?

Comment: @john,In C language, linux is the platform. Please let me know if more details needed

Comment: The method is "GET", "POST", etc. I suggest you run a network sniffer (like Wireshark), and use it to trace you using your browser to access some websites that use Query Parameters to GET or POST methods.  An example would be google finance... https://www.google.com/finance?q=ibm   That said, given the details of HTTP, you should look for a HTTP library (like libcurl) to use, instead of writing it yourself.